# How to populate form input controls from json data in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have a json array, and I want to populate the attributes to Form input for editing, I've struggled for few days but in vain, any possible ways to achieve?

For example, this is the data:

```
customizeInfo = [
    {
        "appId": "App 1",
        "appAttributes": {
            "color": "Red",
            "type": "Productivity"
        }
    },
    {
        "appId": "App 2",
        "appAttributes": {
            "color": "Blue",
            "type": "Productivity",
            "owner": "Pepper Potts"
        }
    }
]
```

This is so far what I have:
But it's impossible to hard code the input control for every attribute

```
render() {
    return (
                {this.props.customizeInfo.map(attr =>
                <Form>
                    <Form.Row>
                        <Form.Group as={Col}>
                            <Form.Label>App Id: <br>
                            </br>{attr.appId}</Form.Label>
                            </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group as={Col}>
                            <Form.Label>Attribute</Form.Label>
                            {attr.appAttributes.color ?<Form.Control type="text" 
                                value={attr.appAttributes.color}></Form.Control> : ''}
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group as={Col}>
                            <Form.Label>Attribute</Form.Label>
                            {attr.appAttributes.type ? <Form.Control type="text"
                                value={attr.appAttributes.type}></Form.Control> : ''}
                        </Form.Group>

                    </Form.Row>
                </Form>)}}
```

And what I want to achieve looks something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFQUs.png)

Comment: Wouldn't it just be something like `document.getElementById("mytext").value = data[0].appId`? Can you edit your question to show us some of the code that you've tried so far?

Comment: thanks for your help, just added some code I have so far

Answer (score 0):

You can archives this with lodash support.

In your component, init state with json data

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = data;
}
```

Then you have your input like this (index is the current position of element in array):

```
<input onChange={event => handleOnChange(event.target.value, index, 'appId')} />
<input onChange={event => handleOnChange(event.target.value, index, 'appAttributes.color')} />
<input onChange={event => handleOnChange(event.target.value, index, 'appAttributes.type')} />
```

And finally, function to handle update state when input field change value

```
function handleOnChange(value, index, changedPath) {
  const newState = _.set(this.state[index], changedPath, value);
  this.setState({
    ...newState
  });
}
```

You can read more about lodash set here => https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set